# What was this major foreign policy reversal by the Vatican in the Middle Ages?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, france, holy-roman-empire, papacy

I made a note about something, but now I can't find it. It was a major shift in the political situation of Europe in the late Middle Ages. Initially one country was the hegemon and the pope organized all of the others against it. Then another country became hegemon, and all of the powers were organized against that one. I think it was Germany, and then France, but I'm not sure when. It was sometime from 1250-1450.

I could be confusing it for something much later, but I don't think so.

Update: I suspect it may have had to do with the lowland countries, aka Holland, Belgium and Flanders. Western powers were allied against one country to prevent it from gaining control of it, and then against another country.

Comment: I think you have it backwards: It was the kings and emperors, with their armies, who struggled to put their own candidates on the Papal throne, and not the other way around. See if the [Avignon Papacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avignon_Papacy), also known as the "Western Schism", rings a bell. This was a period when the French king controlled the Papacy and lasted through pretty much all of the 1300s and into the 1400s.

Comment: The Avingon Papacy may be the period of French hegemony that I am thinking about. Avingnon was actually a Papal State, not a part of France, and they were not 100% tied to the French crown.

Comment: So maybe the anti German period fell before or after that, like with the investiture crisis or later with Sigismund.

Comment: The Vatican is anachronistic.  The popes ruled the Papal States, not the Vatican City, in the middle ages.  The Vatican city was founded in 1929.   In the middle ages the Vatican was merely a region in Rome where St. Peter's church was.  The popes had their seat at the Lateran church, the cathedral of Rome, and the next door Lateran Palace, when not residing in other cities.  In the middle ages people would say "the Lateran" to mean the same thing as "the Vatican" today..

Comment: @Spencer Although the Avignon papacy was overwhelmingly French in complexion (all seven of the popes during the period were French, as were 111 of the 134 cardinals created), it was not so responsive to French pressure as contemporaries assumed or as later critics insisted. Britannica.com

Comment: You are probably referring to the dukes of Burgundy, who had their powerbase in the Low Countries (Flanders, Brabant, Hainault, Holland and Zeeland). Although they and there predecessors were governing the richest part of Western Europe there were no bishops in this region until the 16th century.